# Does my external IP belong to my cable modem or router?

Tags: networking, router, isp, modem

Sorry if others have touched upon this before.
I'm simply asking whether the external IP 'belongs' to the cable modem or my home router. 
If someone is pinging or attacking my external IP is it hitting the router or modem?
Is the modem simply forwarding everything to the router?
If someone is randomly screening my ISP subnet will they see cable modems or routers (assuming separate units)
Thanks

Comment: This belongs over at Superuser.

Answer (score 3):

A modem in the literal sense is just a media converter. It's got no IP address of its own. The term is often used for integrated modem routers as well though.

You should check the status of your router, it should show its external address somewhere.

You likely have only a single public IP address. Without port forwarding, nothing behind that address is visible from the Internet.

Answer (score -1):

Your routable (external) IP should be gotten by your modem.

If your modem has NAT (which basically all do), then it the attack should not be getting to your router.

However, if they're trying ports that you've port-forwarded, or if you have a DMZ set up, then it will be getting to the port-forwarded machine, or DMZ'd area respectively.

The modem should not be forwarding to your router by default (unless a condition is met in the previous paragraph).

The attack should be stopped at your modem.

Comment: This only applies if the modem also contains a router. A modem is just a 'dumb' protocol translator.